# Include @font-face with save page as

Tags: html, css

I can embed a custom font with @font-face. But when the page is saved on my computer to be seen as local, the font is not saved.
I tried this with Firefox, Chrome and Safari. The issue is always the same.

How can I force embed the font with save page as ?

Comment: You can embed the custom font as base64 data directly in your font stylesheet; that way it will have to be saved along with the stylesheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank's @PartiallyFinite, that's idea !

Order of the url calls are important, so I post my @font-face css property:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: "my_custom_font";
    src: url('my_custom_font.eot');
    src: url('my_custom_font.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url(data:font/truetype;charset=utf-8;base64,AAA...AAA=) format('truetype'),
         url('my_custom_font.woff') format('woff'),
         url('my_custom_font.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('my_custom_font.otf') format("opentype"),
         url('my_custom_font.svg#my_custom_font') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant:normal;
}
```

**Notes:**
`url(data:font/truetype)` have to been before `.woff` so firefox use `base64` instead of `.woff`

Tested on Firefox 20.0, Google Chrome 26.0.1410.65, Safari 6.0.